# Why subscribe method is executing after return?

Tags: angular, typescript, alert

I have a form for adding new members. When clicking the submit button, I need to check that the entered email for the new user is not already used. If is used, an alert shows up displaying the following info: "Email is already in use!". If is not used, I redirect to another view and show an alert-success. The thing is that when I call the service method to check if a new member has been created, the function returns the member undefined before filling it in the suscription. Any idea of how to manage to ensure that the suscribe is executed before the return.

Service method:

```
    postMemberContactInfo(memberContactInfo: MemberContact){
          this._http
          .post<MemberContact>(this._membersUrl, memberContactInfo, {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
            responseType: 'json',
            observe: 'body',
          })
          .subscribe({
            next: (value) => { this._newMember = value },
            complete: () => { this.router.navigate([`/members/${this._newMember.id}`], {
              state: this._newMember
            } ) },
            error: (error) => catchError(this.handleError)
          })
    
        return this._newMember;
      }
```

Component ts:

```
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.addMemberForm.invalid) this.addMemberForm.markAllAsTouched();
    else {
      let postedMember = this.memberAddService.postMemberContactInfo({
        name: this.getOrElse("name", ""),
        surname: this.getOrElse("surname", ""),
        role: this.getOrElse("role", ""),
        email: this.getOrElse("email", ""),
        username: this.getOrElse("username", ""),
        comments: this.getOrElse("comments", ""),
      });

      if (postedMember == undefined) this.showAlert = true;
      else {
        this.showAlert = false;
        this.newMemberCreated.emit(postedMember);
      }
    }
  }
```

Template:

```
     <app-generic-alert
      [ngClass]="showAlert ? 'd-block' : 'd-none'"
      [alertType]="'alert-danger'"
      [mainMessage]="'ERROR: '"
      [secondaryMessage]="'Email is already in use!'"
      (closeAlertEvent)="closeAlertHandler()"
    ></app-generic-alert>
```

Comment: Add an isLoaded boolean to the service which you set to true after the POST and on you getter ensure that isloaded is true

Comment: Thank for your reply, but I dont understand the implmentation. Shall I set to true the boolean inside next? And then?

Comment: on the call of postMemberContactInfo set it to false, on next to true

Comment: I know, but where I should put the if statement to check the boolean. The function should in service return always something

Comment: if (postedMember == undefined && service.getIsLoaded) this.showAlert = true;

Comment: or make the boolean a subject and subscribe to it in the component constructor. If it's true, then alert, this seems the wiser strategy considering it would be async, so you want your service to call your component when it's done loading, else you'd probably always get false

Answer (score -2):

your Observable is Asynchronous, while your function runs Synchronously.

This is what is happening in your code:

1. When you call `postMemberContactInfo` it immediately returns the current value of `this._newMember`
2. Later on (maybe a few seconds later) when the BackEnd server responds to the request `this._http.post<MemberContact>` the subscription function is called asynchronously from the observable.

You should embrace the async nature of observables, and not try to make it synchronous... [Here a tutorial](https://remotestack.io/angular-observable-asynchronous-http-request-tutorial/) to get you started

you could change your service to return the observable:

```
postMemberContactInfo(memberContactInfo: MemberContact){
    return this._http
      .post<MemberContact>(this._membersUrl, memberContactInfo, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
        responseType: 'json',
        observe: 'body',
      }).pipe(
        catchError((error) => this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

and subscribe from the Component (something like the following should work):

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.addMemberForm.invalid) this.addMemberForm.markAllAsTouched();
    else {
      this.memberAddService.postMemberContactInfo({
        name: this.getOrElse("name", ""),
        surname: this.getOrElse("surname", ""),
        role: this.getOrElse("role", ""),
        email: this.getOrElse("email", ""),
        username: this.getOrElse("username", ""),
        comments: this.getOrElse("comments", ""),
      }).subscribe(newMember => {

        if (postedMember == undefined) this.showAlert = true;
        else {
          this.showAlert = false;
          this.newMemberCreated.emit(postedMember);

            this.router.navigate([`/members/${newMember.id}`], {
              state: newMember
            } )
        }
      });

      
    }
  }
```

just a note,
Subscribing from the component is considered an anti-pattern, as doing it can cause [memory leaks](https://indepth.dev/posts/1433/rxjs-why-memory-leaks-occur-when-using-a-subject). But this should be enough to get you started.

once you get the hang of the subscriptions, you should avoid subscribing directly, and use the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) from your views instead.

Comment: would appointing this.memberAddService.postMemberContactInfo to a property and then adding onDestroy lifecycle hook where you unsubscribe the property prevent the potential leak?

Comment: _"Subscriptions are Asynchronous"_ That's wrong. Subscriptions are synchronous. That's one of the biggest differences between observables and promises. The observable can contain asynchronous code, but it can be completely synchronous: https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable _"An Observable is a lazily evaluated computation that can synchronously or asynchronously return zero to (potentially) infinite values from the time it's invoked onwards."_

Comment: @JamesD yes, that is one way of doing it. If you look for questions in SO around observable's and memory leaks you will find plenty of options. There are also many written blogs about implementing it

Comment: @JamesD let us ignore the noise... did this answer help you?

Comment: Yes thanks! Just wanted to validate if our implemented method was a correct one

Comment: It is correct, I have this pattern above implemented in at least 10 different applications (100's of times). And without memory leaks... the memory leak issue is a separated matter, but I strongly advise you to get a good understanding of it, so your app can run without them in subscriptions. There are many different ways to tackle it (as per article in the response)